# Getting SitecoreControllers Working With Swagger

Tags: controller

Is there a good way to get Swagger to work with controllers that inherit `SitecoreController`? [I've checked this blog out](https://www.pintle.dk/insights/using-swagger-in-sitecore-solution-as-a-helix-feature/) which uses controllers that inherit from `ApiController`. I thought I could get away with tweaking values in the Swagger related code from `-/api/v1` to `api/sitecore` but nothing was registered for that.

Comment: Please update your question with your code. Could be that it just needs to be slightly changed to make it work.